# Angular2 & Firebase - How to preload form input fields based on URL params?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular-forms

**What I've got**

- A list of projects that display projects from a firebase list (this information is pulled from a projects list service that references a node in firebase)
- A form to add a new project - this allows me to write new data to firebase. The url looks like this: url.com/projects/0/edit
- When I click on a project it takes me to a project details page where the url is appended (*url.com/projects/-key123456*) (this references a different service which references a different firebase node)
- On the project detail page I have an edit button. When clicking this the url looks like this: url.com/projects/-key123456/edit
- To summarise, adding new items is fine. I will write the edit method later. I just need to know how to pre-populate the form based on the selected project

**What I don't know how to achieve**

- How would I go about pre-populating my edit form input fields based on the project selected?

**ProjectEditComponent.html**

```html
<h2>
  projects-edit works!
</h2>


<input #newTitle type='text' placeholder='project title'/>
<input #newReference type='text' placeholder='project reference'/>
<input #newDate type='date' placeholder='project date'/>

<button (click)="submitForm(newTitle.value, newReference.value, newDate.value, newAuditorName.value, newCompanyName.value); newTitle.value=''; newReference.value=''; newDate.value=''; newAuditorName.value=''; newCompanyName.value=''"> 
  Save 
</button>

<a [routerLink]="['/projects']"> Cancel </a>
```

**ProjectEditComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects-edit',
  templateUrl: './projects-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-edit.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsEditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }


  submitForm(title: string, reference: string, date: string, auditorName: string, newCompanyName: string) {


  }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** below is an edit based on progress from the kind @msmolcic!

**ProjectEditComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProjectResolver } from './projects-resolver.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects-edit',
  templateUrl: './projects-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-edit.component.css']
  
})
export class ProjectsEditComponent implements OnInit {

  formName: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,

    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activeRoute.data
      .subscribe(routeData => {
        // Notice that name of the field 'projectData' matches
        // the one you set as alias of the data resolved from
        // the ProjectResolver inside your routing module.
        let projectData = routeData.projectData;

        // Do whatever you want with project data...
        this.formName = this.formBuilder.group({
          // someProperty1 - name of the formControl
          // projectData.someProperty1 - value of your object property
          someProperty1: projectData.project_title
        });
      });


  }

  submitForm(title: string, reference: string, date: string, auditorName: string, newCompanyName: string) {}

}
```

**ProjectsResolver.ts**

I've never created one of these before, so please excuse any stupidity (I've only been learning angular for a week and a half). If I comment out my return data, the page loads and I can navigate. When I include the return line my page breaks without errors.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class ProjectResolver {
    projectsDetails: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    user: Observable<firebase.User>;
    userID;

    constructor(
        private database: AngularFireDatabase,
        private authService: AuthService,
    ) {
        this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.userID = user.uid;
            } else {
                console.log('not signed in apparently');
            }
        });
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        // Notice that name of the parameter 'id' matches the /:id from routing module
        let projectId = route.params['projectId'];

        // Insert the correct fetch logic here, it will then return
        // data to the component after it's resolved.

        //return this.firebaseDb.getProjectById(projectId);
        //return this.projectsDetailsService.getProjectById(projectId);
       // 
       return this.database.list('/project/' + this.userID + '/' + projectId);

    }

}
```

**Routing**

```js
// Modules
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Components
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';
import { ProjectsListComponent } from './projects-list/projects-list.component';
import { ProjectsDetailsComponent } from './projects-details/projects-details.component';
import { ProjectsEditComponent } from './projects-edit/projects-edit.component';
import { IssuesListComponent } from './issues-list/issues-list.component';
import { IssuesDetailsComponent } from './issues-details/issues-details.component';

import { ProjectResolver } from './projects-edit/projects-resolver.service';



// Including const before declaring a property or variable makes something a constant. A constant is a value that other code in our application cannot change. It's a read-only reference that cannot be redefined.
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
    { path:'login', component: LoginPageComponent },
    { path:'projects', component: ProjectsListComponent },
    { path:'projects/:projectId', component: ProjectsDetailsComponent },
    { path:'projects/0/edit', component: ProjectsEditComponent },
    { path:'projects/:projectId/edit', component: ProjectsEditComponent, resolve: { projectData: ProjectResolver } },
    { path:'projects/:projectId/i', component: IssuesListComponent },
    { path:'projects/:projectId/i/:issueId', component: IssuesDetailsComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

// Next, our file needs to export our routes to the rest of the application
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**Project Edit HTMl**

```html
<form [formGroup]="formName">
    <input type="text" formControlName="someProperty1" />
</form>
```

I appreciate your continued time an effort. It feels closer now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a `Resolver` to fetch the data from the `Firebase` before you start initializing your `Component`.

Within your `RoutingModule` you should have setup for your `edit` route:

```
{
    path: '/project/:id/edit',
    component: ProjectEditComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Edit project' // Optional page title
    },
    resolve: {
        // projectData - alias of the data resolved within a resolver
        // ProjectResolver - resolver handling the fetch logic for your Component
        projectData: ProjectResolver
    }
}
```

After that, you must create that `ProjectResolver` somewhere.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectResolver {

    constructor(
        private firebaseDb: NotSureWhatIsTheName
    ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        // Notice that name of the parameter 'id' matches the /:id from routing module
        let projectId = route.params['id'];

        // Insert the correct fetch logic here, it will then return
        // data to the component after it's resolved.
        return this.firebaseDb.getProjectById(projectId);
    }
}
```

Finally, inside of your `Component`, you should get that data and assign it anywhere you want.

```
// Inside the component
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data
        .subscribe(routeData => {
            // Notice that name of the field 'projectData' matches
            // the one you set as alias of the data resolved from
            // the ProjectResolver inside your routing module.
            let projectData = routeData.projectData;

            // Do whatever you want with project data...
        });
}
```

**EDIT:**

In order to bind those values to your form, you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` from `@angular/forms` inside your `ComponentModule`.

```
// If you don't have multiple modules, this should be placed inside your 'app.module.ts'
// Otherwise, place it into your project.module.ts or whatever it's called.

// Import the Module from @angular/forms
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... ], // Whatever you have here
    imports: [ ..., ReactiveFormsModule ], // <- insert ReactiveFormsModule
    ... // Other stuff
```

Once you imported `ReactiveFormsModule`, you can use `FormGroup` and `FormBuilder` inside your `ProjectEditComponent`.

```
// Inside your component
// Import FormGroup and FormBuilder from @angular/forms
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

...
formName: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Lets say you fetched data from the resolver into
    // projectData object as shown before.

    this.formName = this.formBuilder.group({
        // someProperty1 - name of the formControl
        // projectData.someProperty1 - value of your object property
        someProperty1: projectData.someProperty1
    });
}
```

After that, you can bind that `FormGroup` to your `<form>` element inside your `html`.

```
<form [formGroup]="formName">
    <input type="text" formControlName="someProperty1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ah right, this is making more sense. The part I'm having issues with is databinding that to the input fields in the form. Any advice there?

Comment: @MegaTron Amit basically answered you that, I think that you're just missing `ReactiveFormsModule` import inside your `AppModule` or `ProjectModule`. I don't know if you implemented multiple modules. Also, make sure you imported `FormBuilder` inside the constructor of your `Component` in order to create the `FormGroup`.

Comment: a fantastic response. Thank you so much for your time. I've updated my post with my attempt under the 'Edit' heading. It feels really close now. Any help to push this over the line would be massively appreciated.

Comment: @MegaTron Inside of your `Resolver` add `.take(1)` at the end of your call to `Firebase` database. It will actually trigger the call to the database, currently it's hanging because nothing is triggering your `Observable` and data is actually never resolved. So you must call it like this `return this.database.list('/project/' + this.userID + '/' + projectId).take(1);`.

Comment: Thanks. That displays the following error: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.

Comment: @MegaTron Add the following import at the start of your file: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Comment: That fixed the error. The edit page now appears with the one input field, but it's not pre-populated...so close :)

Comment: @MegaTron I just noticed that you've placed object value out of the array. It should be `someProperty1: [projectData.project_title]`. I added [] around the property value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149025/discussion-between-megatron-and-msmolcic).

Comment: is a legend. Appreciate all the time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is fetch the parameters from the url and then build the form using those parameter values.

```
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

export class ProjectsEditComponent implements OnInit {
private myForm: FormGroup; 
constructor(private activeRoute : ActivatedRoute,  private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {

       let title = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['title'];
       let reference = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['reference'];
       let date = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['date']; // should fetch the param named as date

       this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            title: [title, Validators.required],
            reference: [reference, Validators.required],
            date: [date, Validators.required],
       });
 }
}
```

template file

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input #newTitle type='text' formControlName= 'title' placeholder='project title'/>
    <input #newReference type='text' formControlName= 'reference' placeholder='project reference'/>
    <input #newDate type='date' formControlName= 'date' placeholder='project date'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. A couple of questions...1) I only have one param to check, and that's the url: "url.com/projects/-KEY12345"...the last part being the firebase ID for that project. 2) I'm getting errors that 'fb' and 'validators' cannot be found

Comment: For Q1 : with that id are you fetching the data again? Q2. Updated the answer and please add the imports accordingly.